Cannot connect to GitHub on Mac
I'm using Mac Ventura 13.6.6 and git version 2.39.3 (Apple Git-145). Due to my location, I have to use VPNs to use Google, GitHub, etc. It has been working well.
Since several days ago, I realize that I cannot connect to GitHub anymore, while other sites work fine. Opening github.com in a browser returns ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED as follows.

Git clone and git push return an error fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/softtimur/code.git/': LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443.
nano ~/.gitconfig gives
# This is Git's per-user configuration file.
[user]
# Please adapt and uncomment the following lines:
#       name = Timur Soft
#       email = softtimur@Timur-MacBook-Pro.local
[user]
        name = softtimur
        email = softtimur@gmail.com
[filter "lfs"]
        clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
        smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
        process = git-lfs filter-process
        required = true
[http]
        sslVerify = true

I tried to modify sslVerify to false, but it still did not work.
I changed VPNs, it still did not work.
I also tried to use the internet from hotspot of a foreigner phone number, thus VPN is not necessary. Websites like Google work, while github.com does not work.
Does anyone know how to fix this connection problem?
PS: $ openssl s_client -connect github.com:443 -msg returns
Connecting to 192.30.255.113
CONNECTED(00000005)
>>> TLS 1.0, RecordHeader [length 0005]
    16 03 01 01 39
>>> TLS 1.3, Handshake [length 0139], ClientHello
    01 00 01 35 03 03 7c de de f4 93 d3 e6 f9 eb 2a
    5c 8f 2e 80 5f 4d 66 75 2d 80 8b 20 72 42 88 97
    15 6d 92 af 0f e9 20 5b 26 bd 5c 2d 99 c7 0b 1c
    be 66 43 b1 57 f3 21 4d f2 ca c0 07 7b fa 00 84
    d7 6b 8c 5e a0 c4 4f 00 3e 13 02 13 03 13 01 c0
    2c c0 30 00 9f cc a9 cc a8 cc aa c0 2b c0 2f 00
    9e c0 24 c0 28 00 6b c0 23 c0 27 00 67 c0 0a c0
    14 00 39 c0 09 c0 13 00 33 00 9d 00 9c 00 3d 00
    3c 00 35 00 2f 00 ff 01 00 00 ae 00 00 00 0f 00
    0d 00 00 0a 67 69 74 68 75 62 2e 63 6f 6d 00 0b
    00 04 03 00 01 02 00 0a 00 16 00 14 00 1d 00 17
    00 1e 00 19 00 18 01 00 01 01 01 02 01 03 01 04
    00 23 00 00 00 16 00 00 00 17 00 00 00 0d 00 30
    00 2e 04 03 05 03 06 03 08 07 08 08 08 1a 08 1b
    08 1c 08 09 08 0a 08 0b 08 04 08 05 08 06 04 01
    05 01 06 01 03 03 03 01 03 02 04 02 05 02 06 02
    00 2b 00 05 04 03 04 03 03 00 2d 00 02 01 01 00
    33 00 26 00 24 00 1d 00 20 f6 93 ac 16 73 b2 0d
    4e 61 76 7b 16 2c 91 1e a7 b4 e6 93 95 39 d7 0f
    31 4c ea e2 7e ee aa 09 26
>>> TLS 1.0, RecordHeader [length 0005]
    15 03 01 00 02
>>> TLS 1.3, Alert [length 0002], fatal decode_error
    02 32
C0F7D849F87F0000:error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:692:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 325 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
This TLS version forbids renegotiation.
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---


Does your endpoint trust the issuer of the GitHub certificate (Sectigo)?

Check if your computer time is correct

Your problem is not with certificate verification or CA trust but way before that. It is not unlikely that your (VPN) IP address has been blocked by a web application firewall. Unfortunately, bad actors are also often using public VPN providers. Maybe try a different VPN or a different server location on your VPN.
